# URL of a collection in Backbone for RESTful interaction

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, backbone.js

Here is a collection I define in backbone.js

```
    var List=Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Item,
        url: "TodoApp/index.php/todo"
    });
    var list=new List
```

Then I created a Model in the collection with an ID=80
Now, when I do list.fetch();
It will make a call to 
        "TodoApp/index.php/todo/80"

However, at the backend, using Codeigniter, I really need to have

```
    TodoApp/index.php/todo/get/82.........where get is a function I defined to access DB
```

So, should I change the Collection url to "TodoApp/index.php/todo/get"

But again, that's not really where the resource is located?

Answer (score 0):

In route.php try:

```
$route['todo/(:num)'] = "todo/get/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

HERE is what I ended up doing.

I renamed the index of the controller to resource
therefore using a URL of:
        TodoApp/index.php/todo/resource

When getting a GET request at 
        TodoApp/index.php/todo/resource/80

extract the second segment of the URI and read from DB with that.